# The location crisis を + が + で + に

Tags: particles

I realize that an explanation of when to use に or で must be everywhere on this site but i have a rather peculiar question on this topic.

For me alot of things in japanese atart out as "memorize this" and eventually much later actually understand whats going on.

One thing i have noticed is that the to に or で topic for me at least has been become somewhat based on logic and largely based on just memorizing whether to に or で for literally every verb i know.

The logic portion of my brain has been able to make the following deductions and i would like to know if they are actually true.

1) を particles seem to take exclusively で for locations.

2) if you cant find a way to put a を  particle into the sentence then it must use the に particle.

(This statement is twofold, as i am asserting that certain particles which must use が like ある and いる  must always use a ni particle.

But i am also asserting that if theres nothing to logically use the を or が particle on that the statement must use に  basically im saying if the thing you would normally use を on becomes something you would use the by means of で on instead it must use に.)

Obviously there are some structures like eru or rareru that can change a を to a が and i want to exclude all those cases from my above statements.

It is of course impossible for both my assumtions to be true. I know they cannot be because its incredibly straight forward and simple; and i have read many textbooks and articles on the subject and the best of them can only be described as an pathetic attempt to sort of maybe kinda think about almost trying to explaining something with any attempt at being definitive.

So my questions are when do you need to use に with the を particle?

Secondly when must you use で with a verb that can only use the particle が. Things such as conjugations that change を particles to が  dont count. As well as verbs who you can interchange を and が to emphasized the noun are also off limits.

Although i doubt this will complely answer my question of when to に or when to で.
 I feel it may allow me to reduce it to a problem of "is it possible that i could replace that が particle with a を particle and not drastically alter the sentence's meaning." It would at least be a vast improvement over memorizing every fking verbs particle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

を/が are only indirectly connected to で/に. The problem is compounded by the fact that に and で both have multiple uses.

- で is used for instruments (*I was eating **with** a fork*, *I came **by** bus*, *I spoke **in** English*)
- で is used for locations of actions (*I am eating **at** a restaurant*, *I am running **in** the park*)
- に is used as a recipient (*I gave the dog **to** Moa*)
- に is used as a destination (*I am walking **into** the park*)
- に is used as an adverb marker (*Please read quiet**ly***)
- に is used as an agent in a passive sentence (*I was punched into the shoulder **by** Moa*)
- に is used as a location of states (*I am sat **at** a restaurant*, *I live **in** Tokyo*)

I believe you are confused about the last one of each, location of actions vs location of states. While states typically don't have objects (which accounts for your observation that を doesn't go with に), actions may or may not have objects:

- レストランで食べました *I ate **at** the restaurant*
- レストランでステーキを食べました *I ate steak **at** the restaurant*

States are typically verbs of position (standing, sitting, lying...) and verbs of location (being at, living at, floating...), unless I'm forgetting something, so the list of verbs using に for location is rather limited. Pretty much all other verbs express actions, and use で for location.

Comment: Your answer really helped me.  Though it didnt quite answer verbs that must use が seem to mostly use ni  situation for me.  However it defintly made it a bit clearer on the sentences that can use ga but dont have to.  Thanks

Comment: There is no "verbs that must use が". You could say either that all verbs can use がand you could say that no verbs need to use が since it might not be overtly expressed, so I don't know what you mean here. Can you clarify?

Comment: You cannot say ねこ を います.  Or ペン を あります.

Comment: There are more ill write them out when i get home.

Comment: That's correct, there are verbs that do not permit を; but this has nothing to do with が. There are no verbs that _require_ が: both います and あります (without が) are perfectly valid sentences (given appropriate context). There are also no verbs where が is _not allowed_: ステーキを食べた and モアがステーキを食べた are both okay.

Comment: That right there is my problem.  When a sentence uses the particle が figuring out whether i need to use ni or de as the location particle.  (Its very common ina test that one will be given such a sentence and asked to place the location particle and the only way to tell tell for sure as far as i can tell is to memorize every verbs location particle. )

Comment: As I told you in the answer: が has nothing to do with it. Location and position verbs use に for location, and there is a very short list of them (if you can't sort out the logic of what is a position or a location verb). Remember "this is a state verb" where needed, and use で by default for all other verbs; there is really no need to remember it for every word (and no point in looking at が).